# jQuery addclass during iteration but only change the current div

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change divs depending on whether a JSON objects array is either value 1 or 0. My problem is that this code updates all divs during each iteration rather than only the corresponding one to the loop index.

Firstly I used the jQuery .css method but that only does the first one which is fair enough... Next I tried using .addClass and then finally $(this) with either .closest, .descendants and some other similar filtering methods.

I have checked the expected output on console and this is fine. We'll say there are 2 divs after each other and I only want to change whatever one is relevant for the current loop index. Am I correct in saying that addClass will always change them all in this case, even when using .each or even a for loop?

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box">
```

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('js/test.json', function (step1) {
        $.each(step1.object, function (index, value) {
            if (value == 1) {
                $(".box").addClass("engaged");
                console.log('Engaged');
            } else {
                $(".box").addClass("disengaged");
                console.log('Disengaged');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should get you what you want. Without having a better test setup I can't verify it though:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('js/test.json', function (step1) {
        var $boxes = $(".box");
        $.each(step1.object, function (index, value) {
            if (value == 1) {
                $boxes.eq(index).addClass("engaged");
                console.log('Engaged');
            } else {
                $boxes.eq(index).addClass("disengaged");
                console.log('Disengaged');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code will find all the boxes and then the `eq` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)) will select the one that is at the equivalent index to the value you are testing.

Comment: If you need to do extra processing, I would use this route. If you are only adding/removing/toggling a class, I would go with Arun's answer.

Comment: I went for this one, both did work perfectly though thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration you need to target the `box` element in the current index, but when you say `$('.box').addClass()` it will add the class to all the `box` elements.

You can also use another way to do it as below,

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('js/test.json', function(step1) {
    $(".box").addClass(function(i) {
      return step1.object[i] == 1 ? 'engaged' : 'disengaged'
    })
  });
});
```